# the html not showing value of php(UPDATED)

Tags: php, html, variables

UPDATED: I have a variable in PHP `mailuid` that I want to show in my HTML. It displays the error the value of mailuid is undefined on the webpage. How can I show the value of height to html page?

index.php

```
<?php
require "header.php";

?>

    <main>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styl.css">
        <div class="wrapper-main">
            <section class="section-default">
                <h2><?php echo "$mailuid" ?></h2>
                <?php
                
                ?>
            </section>

        </div>

    </main>


<?php
require "footer.php";
?>
```

loginbackend.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['login-submit'])) {

    require 'db.php';
  
    $mailuid = $_POST['mailuid'];
    $password = $_POST['pwd'];

    if (empty($mailuid) || empty($password)) {
        header("Location: ./index.php?error=emptyfields");
        exit();
    } else {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uidUsers=? OR emailUsers=?;";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
            header("Location: ./index.php?error=sqlerror");
            exit();
         } else  {
             mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $mailuid, $mailuid);
             mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
             $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
             if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $pwdCheck = password_verify($password, $row['pwdUsers']);
                if($pwdCheck == false) {
                    header("Location: ./index.php?error=wrongpwd");
                    exit();
                } else if ($pwdCheck == true) {
                     session_start();
                     $_SESSION['userId'] = $row['idUsers'];
                     $_SESSION['userUid'] = $row['uidUsers'];
                    
                     $username = substr($mailuid, 0, strpos($mailuid, "@"));
                     
                     header("Location: ./index.php?login=success".$username);
                     exit();
                } else {
                       header("Location: ./index.php?error=wrongpwd");
                       exit();
                }
             } else {
                 header("Location: ./index.php?error=nouser");
                 exit();
             }
         }

    }

} else {
    header("Location: ./signup.php");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Try `<h1 ><?php echo $height; ?></h1>`

Comment: **height is undefined** where ??

Comment: it because you are using 2 files and `index.php` doesn't require `data.php`

Comment: @xKobalt It displays the same error

Comment: How is `data.php` and `index.php` related? Why do you expect a variable from one file to be available in another file? Are you including one in the other? If so, show us where and how that happens.

Comment: @aXuser264 I meant it says as the error on the webpage. I have updated the answer, sorry it was a bit confusing.

Comment: @AryWibowo If index.php doesn't require data.php how would I get the value of `height` from data.php if I don't use it?

Comment: `<h1>` has no src AFAIK

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I have a login system and the login details are in loginbackend.php file, so I was trying to get the username from that file to index.php. So I asked here as an example.

Comment: hey, ur sure that ur making a `POST` req

Comment: This is one of those situations where you need to show and explain the actual code. If you define a variable in one file, that file needs to either be included in the other file, or it needs to include the other file. There's no way to answer this question when we have no clue what your real setup is. Variables defined on one file isn't automatically available in other files.

Comment: @aXuser264 Yes, I am making a post request

Comment: @MagnusEriksson It's a bunch of code its why I didn't post it here

Comment: works like charm in my reproduced sample, so please give a example that reproduces ur problem

Comment: That's why you need to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You don't need to post all your code, only the relevant one. You also need to explain how those files are related. That's a minimum for us to be able to understand what's going on.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I will update my question

Comment: @ikea, i mean your index.php doesn't require/include data.php, thats why $height on data.php can't be read or undefined. you should add `<?php include 'data.php'?>` in first line in your index.php

Comment: I don't think it makes sense for us to try to solve the above code. As far as we know, the real issue can be something completely different than a file not being included. It could just as well be a scoping issue.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I have updated my answer, sorry for making it confusing.

Comment: When you redirect a request, your `header('location: ....')`, the browser will make a completely new request to the server. No variables you set in the previous request, in `loginbackend.php`, will exist anymore. If you some data to be persistent between requests, you can use sessions, alternatively pass it in the URL, like you're doing with `?error=...` params (which allows you to fetch it from the `$_GET`-variable on the new page).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Can you write it as a answer how can I actually make it work? I can show the mailuid in the url, but that's all I can do. Can you show how to pass from url to html using GET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your latest comment:

To get the mailuid from the URL (GET parameters) add the following code to your index.php

```
<?PHP 
require "header.php";
$mailuid = !empty($_GET['mailuid']) ? $_GET['mailuid'] : null;
// You can also specify the default value to be used instead of `null` if the `mailuid` is not specified in the URL.
?>
<main>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styl.css">
<div class="wrapper-main">
<section class="section-default">
    <h2><?php echo "$mailuid"?></h2>
 </section>
</div>
</main>
<?php
require "footer.php";
?>
```

From PHP7 you can use

```
$mailuid = $_GET['mailuid'] ?? null;
```

instead of

```
$mailuid = !empty($_GET['mailuid']) ? $_GET['mailuid'] : null;
```

Comment: Use `$mailuid = $_GET['mailuid'] ?? null;` or the script will throw an undefined index warning if the param is missing, like on the initial load.

Comment: `<h2><?php echo "$mailuid"?></h2>
  <?php

$mailuid = $_GET['mailuid'];

  ?>` Is this right way of doing? As it shows the same error

Comment: @ikea Glad to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

**The mistake you've made:**
I think you're confusing forms and file including with how post works.

**Let me explain:**
A form sends data to the server, which is then pushed into the $_POST global variable. You can read this data and use this data easily by echoing or dumping it.

This is what you should do:
In this case, your data value will be empty as you're not passing anything to it.

You can solve this by creating a form and passing it to your PHP file.
You can also just require your php script.
Normally you would put data.php in your action, but since you wish to use the variable before you entered the form, you have to include it first.

index.html

```
<?php require 'data.php'; ?>
<form method="POST" action="">
   <h1>Height: <?=$height?></h1>
   <input type="text" placeholder="Enter the height..." name="height">

   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

data.php

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $height = $_POST['height'];
} else {
    $height = 0; //Default height
}
```

My apologies if i didn't get your question properly.

===========================================

Option B, if this is what you mean, is just doing this:

index.html

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
       <?php 
       require 'data.php'; //Get the data.php file so we can use the contents
       ?>
       <h1><?php echo $height; ?></h1>
    </div>
</body>
```

data.php

```
<?php 
$height = 100; //Height variable
```